# Putting a navbar in a precise position

Tags: html, css

I want the nav to be in the right bottom (in the header of course).

I don't want bootstrap solution but I only want it with pure CSS and HTML. Thanks :)

**Code:**

```css
header {
  background: #1abc9c;
  height: 150px;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 130px 0px 90px 0px;
}
nav ul {} nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 3px;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 180%;
}
nav > a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><b>Home</b></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>About</b></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>Portfolio</b></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>Contact</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="first">
  </section>
  <section id="second">
  </section>
  <section id="third">
  </section>
  <section id="fourth">
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify css rules as follows. This will work

```
header {
  background: #1abc9c;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;

} 
nav {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
nav ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a { 
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  font-size:180%;
  }
nav a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:white;
}
  clear{
    clear:both;
  }
  #first{
    float:left;
    background:#f1c40f;
    height:400px;
  }
   #second{
    float:left;
    background:#f1c40f;
    height:400px;
  }
    #third{
    float:left;
    background:#f1c40f;
    height:400px;
  }
    #fourth{
    float:left;
    background:#f1c40f;
    height:400px;
  }
```

Comment: It worked i appreciate it  ,but the color of links is no more white

Comment: You must include the css you already defined for `a` . I didn't mention that in my answer, because that was proper and has no change

Comment: i didnt remove the css defined for `a`

Comment: If you are worrying about the hover underline color you have to change the style rule to `nav a:hover{}` in place of `nav > a:hover` because `>` selector is used for first level child selectors and in your case `a` is not first level child of `nav`

Comment: just one last thing im trying to put the four divisions under each other can you help me with that ?

Comment: what are the four division can you create provide snippet or fiddle link

Comment: I am not getting what are the four division you wanted under each other ?  Can you describe your problem specifically

Comment: the four divs wich everyone have an id (firstnsecond third and fourth)

Comment: So do you want to open the crresponding numbered division on menu item click ?

Comment: that would be okay,but it's not my real problem ,i m a newbie im trying to put the divs under each other.

Comment: please enter chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/88251/private-discussion?tab=general)

Comment: it tells me "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"

Comment: Can we further discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88252/migrated-from-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-32282418-putting-a-navbar-in-a-p

Comment: same problem :/ it doesnt matter thank you for your help anyway im gonna find a solution :)